# Can't set Ifilter debugging on Vista. "Error writing value's contents" on Gathering Manager:DebugFilters

Tags: windows, security, winapi, ifilter

I am unable to set Ifilter debugging on Vista as per [these instructions](http://blogs.msdn.com/ifilter/archive/2007/02/06/debugging-ifilters-with-wds-3-0-and-windows-vista.aspx).

I used regedit to set

```
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows Search\Gathering Manager:Debug Filters
```

to `1`, but when I click OK, I get this error :

> Cannot edit DebugFilters. Error writing value's contents.

I tried changing the permissions on the registry branch -- it does appear to be a permissions issue.  The Administrators entry has "Special Permissions" checked, and the "Read" and "Full" greyed out. However, I can check them but  when I click OK to save that change, I get this error:

> Unable to save permissions on Gathering Manager.  Access is denied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer.  You have to right-click the registry branch "folder", choose Permissions, then Advanced.  On the Owner tab, set yourself as the owner.  This lets you change the permissions.

Details:
http://www.tjitjing.com/blog/2007/02/regedit-cannot-create-value-error.html